# Query a table and only match rows where a field matches "STRING"

Tags: rethinkdb

During prototyping I have imported a bunch of Facebook posts into a table in batches. After the first batch I did a bulk update to convert the `"created_date"` column from string to a native timestamp (using the handy `r.ISO8601` function):

`r.db('db').table('table').update({'created_date': r.ISO8601(r.row('created_date'))`

On the second pass, when I try to repeat this update, the server throws an error because not all row fields are of type `STRING` (ie the ones previously converted), which is what `ISO861` expects.

I've already tried to filter on `r.row('created_date').typeOf() == "STRING"` but got no matches. I can't find any other way to refer to the STRING type as an object rather than a literal string either.

I know that I could import these out and do the if/else logic in code, but I'm interested to understand if there's a native query that will filter out rows that match a certain type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `eq` for comparing like this:

```
r.row('created_date').typeOf().eq("STRING")
```

Using `==` only works on some language support operator overrding.